# Where is a TikzPicture main cache or database?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a bunch of code snippets like the one below. I would like to display all of the tikzpictures... Is there a cache or database I can pull these tikzpictures images from? Is there a command I can use within LaTeX to list these pictures.

Also, how can I list the .tex files being used within LaTeX code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{scope}[shift={(100.0,1706.0)},nonzero rule]
  \path[draw=.,fill=.,line width=1.600pt] (2130.0000,-582.0000) ..
    controls (2130.0000,-299.3333) and (2030.0000,-58.0000) ..
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

God Bless You,
AO

Comment: a tikz picture is just tex code by default it is just executed as encounted just like `\section` or `\frac` it is not cached in any way.

Comment: If you want to create a "cache" of all the tikzpictures, you could externalise them, see e.g. section "52 Externalization Library" of the tikz user manual. However your question sounds like an xy-problem. Can you add a bit more information about the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: IF you created them using class standalone, you can include them as pdf using the graphicx package https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx. // BTW, don't forget `transform shape`when you play with `scale` .. see im https://tikz.dev

Comment: @MS-SPO The code looks like the output of svg2tikz. It normally does not need `transform shape`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, thanks for the hint. Can be. Nevertheless, sooner or later this might appear in plain-Tikz code too. Just a hint for the OP

Comment: Using standalone class with [tikz] will create a PDF with each tikzpicture on a separate page.  `\includegraphics` will allow tyou to select the page desired (by number).